# maven not working with Java on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, maven

I downloaded the latest version of JDK8 for Mac OS X and also installed maven.  However, I seem to be having an incompatibility between Java and maven:

```
myusername$ mvn -version
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:254)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getMainClass(Launcher.java:144)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:266)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

I am using:

```
myusername$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_45
```

How can I make Java and maven compatible with each other?

Tried instructions from possible duplicate question: [Maven Installation OSX Error Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255495/maven-installation-osx-error-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0):

```
myusername$ export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.6.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home
myusername$ mvn -version
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.6.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven Installation OSX Error Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255495/maven-installation-osx-error-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

Comment: maybe `JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly`, so you  need to properly set JAVA_HOME

Comment: If you've downloaded the latest version of JDK8, why does your JAVA_HOME point to a JDK 6 directory?

Comment: it is messing up at the `bin/java` stage

Comment: @Zoltán how can i manually set it?

Comment: find the path to your java binary files and set it as java home

Comment: okay it is fixed now... same problem though... same error message

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `JAVA_HOME` of 1.6.x Java versions on the Mac is `/Library/Java/Home` only Java 7 and higher are installed below `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`

Execute `/usr/libexec/java_home -version 1.8` to get the current 1.8 Java Home. I use `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -version 1.8)` to set my correct `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the `/bin/java` stage that it is trying to run

Comment: Execute `/usr/libexec/java_home -version 1.8` to get the current 1.8 Java Home. I use `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -version 1.8)` to set my correct `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: I got it!  Thank you!!  The issue was that I downloaded Java8 but didn't use that export command to update.  There were incompatibilities in the current version of Maven and my old version of Java 1.6.  Looks like the latest version of Maven is better suited with JDK8.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same exact error, no matter what JVM target I chose. The solution was to [downgrade maven](https://dtucker.co.uk/hack/rolling-back-to-maven-30x-on-osx.html):

```
brew uninstall maven
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install maven30
```