# mvn wont recognize proper java

Tags: java, macos, maven, unsupported-class-version

So I am having pretty much the exact same problem as this guy:

[Maven Installation OSX Error Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255495/maven-installation-osx-error-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

Nothing in there is working for me....I think the problem is in my symlinks somewhere.  I'de defined $JAVA_HOME in .bash_profile and java -version correctly reports the version.  However, for some reason, mvn is trying to use an old version of java.

Here's a list of everything on my machine:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -verbose
Matching Java Virtual Machines (5):
    1.8.0_40, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_79, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_75, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, i386:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I want to be using 1.8.  And mvn to recognize it.

If I run this:

```
ls -l `which java`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 May 24 22:46 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

And then if I run:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java -version
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

I do notice this symlink out of order:

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
ls -l
total 64
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 May 24 22:46 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 May 24 22:46 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 May 24 22:46 1.5 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 May 24 22:46 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 May 24 22:46 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 May 24 22:46 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel  238 May 24 22:46 A
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    1 May 24 22:46 Current -> A
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   59 May 24 22:46 CurrentJDK -> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents
```

Is "CurrentJDK" actually used anywhere?  And how do I update the link?

I can't understand whats going on...everything seems to be pointed to the new Java, where and how is mvn reading Java 6 (Unsupported major.minor version 51.0)?

Answer (score 0):

The symbolic link in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions was pointing to the old JDK.

Running these commands fixed it:

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions 
sudo rm CurrentJDK
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/ CurrentJDK
```