# What Version of Maven is Compatible with Java 6?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I have to work in an older project that requires java 6 to run, as there are references to depreciated sun classes that have been removed in future versions. As part of the process, I changed my jdk from 8 in my system path to point to java 6 jdk. After doing so I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:254)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getMainClass(Launcher.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:266)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

This is is similar to [Maven Installation OSX Error Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255495/maven-installation-osx-error-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0) and [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: a (Unsupported major.minor version 51.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237536/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-a-unsupporte) however I'm not looking to upgrade, I'm looking to find a version of maven that is compatible with java 6. Any ideas on which version is compatible and where I can download/install it from for mac?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to [the Maven release history page](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html), the last Maven version that works with JDK1.6 is 3.2.5.

Note that it's better to keep using the newer Maven version (and keep Java 8 as the default in the system path), and tell Maven that the project it's building should compile with source set to 1.6 - see [source and target documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) for more info. Reverting to an old Maven will remove the bug fixes / enhancements of the newer versions.

Comment: Keeping Java8 and then compiling for Java6 may however lead to some issues, please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35915323/5606016) on the why and how you could prevent runtime troubles using Maven

Comment: Download from https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.2.5/binaries/ and can install similar to direction given on http://www.mkyong.com/maven/install-maven-on-mac-osx/

Comment: @A.DiMatteo Interesting post. And as far as I can understand from the comments there, the best thing is to make sure the used APIs are compatible (at least until JDK9 is here).

Comment: @AR.3 indeed, and the animal sniffer plugin makes a great job, I used at work in similar scenarios (I hit a runtime error and didn't have fun I must say :)). Comments from Stuart Marks make it kind of stamped-approved, but yes, Java 9 will change the game

Answer (score 3):

If you have the problem you need to build with JDK 6 but you would like run Maven with JDK 7 (cause you like to use Maven 3.3+) you should consider using [toolchain](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) which makes this independent from each other.