# mvn -v gives me "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0"

Tags: java, macos, maven, terminal

I type `mvn -v` into the terminal and it gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:254)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getMainClass(Launcher.java:144)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:266)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

The java version I am using is the current Java 8, 
my `$JAVA_HOME` variable is set to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home`.

`java -v` gives me

```
java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)
```

so that should all be correct, right? Any idea what I might be missing here?

EDIT: As it turns out, the `export JAVA_HOME` line was missing from my `.bash_profile`. Fixed thanks to the correct answer below.

Comment: There's only one possible reason for this error: you are using an older version of Java. A Java version other than Java 8 is being picked up somehow on your system.

Comment: 51 means it was built for 1.7 so as previous answer indicates, you have a mismatch of Java-version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven Installation OSX Error Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255495/maven-installation-osx-error-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

Comment: Have you set M2_HOME somewhere? If so remove it ...

Comment: Running `mvn --version` will tell you what version of not only Maven you have, but, also, what version of Java Maven finds on the `PATH`.

Comment: @carlspring No it won't, not if it first crashes with `UnsupportedClassVersionError`. The questioner actually did run `mvn -v` which is a synonym for `mvn --version`.

Comment: @JeremyP: You are right. In my mind, I seem to have confused `-v` with `-X` (thinking it stood for verbose, like many other tools do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the exception is because the library being loaded is too new for the version of Java running. Version 51.0 is Java 7, so `mvn` must be running with Java 6 or earlier. This is not up for dispute, no matter what you think `JAVA_HOME` is.

The command `mvn` is a shell script that executes the `mvn` Java executable. It's quite short and easily understandable.

You can confirm the version of Java running by inserting

```
echo "$JAVA_HOME"
echo "$JAVACMD"
"$JAVACMD" -version
```

just before the line at the end that starts with

```
exec "$JAVACMD" ....
```

It's probably going to Apple's version of java in `/System/Library`, you almost certainly don't have JAVA_HOME set completely correctly.

**EDIT**

From the comments, it seems that `mvn` thinks `$JAVA_HOME` is

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current‌​JDK/Home
```

This is the location of the Apple JDK which is based on Java 1.6.  The correct way to fix the issue is to make sure that JAVA_HOME is set correctly in the right `.profile` or `.bash_profile` depending on which shell you use.

The following is my `.profile` with all non mvn related bits removed.

```
 JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8/Contents/Home
 M2_HOME=/usr/local/maven
 M2=$M2_HOME/bin
 MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512M"
 export M2_HOME M2 JAVA_HOME MAVEN_OPTS

 PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH:$M2

 EDITOR=vim 
 export EDITOR
```

Comment: Absolutely correct.  
That did confirm it's using Java 6.  
How would I go about sorting that out? I'm hardly an expert on these matters.

Comment: @BlueTooth4269 What value of JAVA_HOME did it print out?.

Comment: `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home  
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java  
java version "1.6.0_65"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)`

Comment: So JAVA_HOME is set to the Apple JDK. Set it correctly before running mvn.

Comment: How would I do that? Typing `echo $ JAVA_HOME` in the terminal gives me  `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home`.

Comment: @BlueTooth4269 Also check thatthe mvn script is not setting it.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved it - I was missing the export line in my .bash_profile. Added it and it works - brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if `/apache-maven/bin/mvn`(incase of linux/unix) or `/apache-maven/bin/mvn.cmd`(in case of windows) file in apache maven installation has JAVA_HOME set to some old version of Java.

Its possible that its using the old java version.